How to assign a column value to NULL in a select, in case this column does not fulfill a condition, using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause?
I have some users in my cluster, whose usernames end with a suffix like "_suffix". Some of them have an username that include a database name plus the suffix, like "dbname_suffix", others have some other name plus the suffix. I am trying to select all the usernames that end with the suffix in one column, matching the users that have the "dbname_suffix" pattern in their usernames with a second column where I have databases.

If the "dbname" part of the username matches the name of a database, then I show them together side by side on both columns;
If the user name does not match the name of any database, then the database column shows the value NULL;
And if there is a database that does not have any username match, then the username column shows the value NULL.

I tried to solve it like this:
select
    pd.datname as DB_NAME,
    pr.rolname as DB_ROLE
from
    pg_roles pr
cross join
    pg_database pd
where
    pr.rolname like ''||pd.datname||'_suffix'
or
    pr.rolname like '%_suffix'
and
    pd.datname not in ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')
and case
        when
            pr.rolname like '%_suffix' and pr.rolname not like ''||pd.datname||'_suffix'
        then
            pd.datname = 'NULL'
        when
            pd.datname is not null and pr.rolname not like ''||pd.datname||'_suffix' or pr.rolname not like '%_suffix'
        then
            pr.rolname = 'NULL'
    end
order by
    pd.datname;

And I would like to get something like this:
DB_NAME     DB_ROLE
mydb        mydb_suffix
newdb       newdb_suffix
NULL        test_suffix
test_db     NULL

However I am getting something like this:
DB_NAME     DB_ROLE
mydb        mydb_suffix
newdb       newdb_suffix
postgres    postgres_suffix

I am not only getting only usernames that match the pattern "dbname_suffix", but I am also getting the postgres database as output, even though I have set a condition that I don't want to get this database as an output.
Could anyone show me, please, what I am not doing correctly to get the expected result?

Try a combination of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN with a UNION to cover all the cases, check below, I combined LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, and UNION to retrieve matching and non-matching database names and user roles with a specified suffix, ensuring to exclude specific system databases. Hope that helps!
SELECT 
    pd.datname AS DB_NAME,
    pr.rolname AS DB_ROLE
FROM 
    pg_database pd
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_roles pr
ON 
    pr.rolname = pd.datname || '_suffix'
WHERE 
    pd.datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')

UNION

SELECT 
    NULL AS DB_NAME,
    pr.rolname AS DB_ROLE
FROM 
    pg_roles pr
WHERE 
    pr.rolname LIKE '%_suffix'
AND 
    pr.rolname NOT LIKE ANY (SELECT datname || '_suffix' FROM pg_database)

UNION

SELECT 
    pd.datname AS DB_NAME,
    NULL AS DB_ROLE
FROM 
    pg_database pd
WHERE 
    pd.datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')
AND 
    pd.datname || '_suffix' NOT IN (SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles)

ORDER BY 
    DB_NAME;


This seems good, but somehow this condition in the second select "AND pr.rolname NOT LIKE ANY (SELECT datname||'_connect' FROM pg_database)" is still giving roles that contain a database name in their names as output. Would you know why? I am trying to figure it out.

I replaced the "LIKE ANY" by the "NOT IN" operator and I got the expected output.

What you are looking for is a full outer join, not a cross join:
SELECT pd.datname AS db_name, pr.rolname AS db_role
FROM pg_database pd
FULL JOIN pg_roles pr ON pr.rolname = pd.datname || '_suffix'
WHERE pd.datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1');


You should create a cte to collect all the db names and all suffixes from both tables (databases and roles) and  use that cte to get the result. Created some sample data to work with instead of pg_databases and pg_roles.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  databases ( DB_ID, DB_NAME ) AS 
    ( Select 1, 'postgres' Union All 
      Select 2, 'template0' Union All 
      Select 3, 'DB_A' Union All 
      Select 4, 'DB_B' Union All 
      Select 5, 'DB_C' 
    ),
  roles ( ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME ) AS
    ( Select 1, 'postgres_owner' Union All 
      Select 2, 'DB_A_user1' Union All 
      Select 3, 'DB_B_user3' Union All 
      Select 4, 'something_user1' Union All 
      Select 5, 'something_someuser' 
    ),

... here is the CTE that collects db names and suffixes ...
  db_suffixes AS
    ( Select Distinct SOURCE, ROLE_NAME, DB, SUFFIX
      From ( Select Distinct 
                     'Roles' as SOURCE,
                      r.ROLE_NAME, 
                  Case When Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) > 0 Then
                      Case When Position('_' In SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1)) = 0
                           Then SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, 1, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) - 1)
                      Else SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, 1, Position(SubStr( SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1), Position('_' In SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1)) + 1 ) in r.ROLE_NAME) - 2) 
                      End
                 Else Null
                 End as DB,
                 Case When Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) > 0 Then
                      Case When Position('_' In SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1)) = 0
                           Then SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1)
                      Else SubStr( SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1), Position('_' In SubStr(r.ROLE_NAME, Position('_' In r.ROLE_NAME) + 1)) + 1 )
                      End 
                 Else r.ROLE_NAME
                 End as SUFFIX  
            From   roles r
           UNION ALL
            Select    'Dbs', Null, d.DB_NAME, Null
            From      databases d
          )
     Where DB Not In('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')
  ) 

Note: This handles possibility of 1 underscore ( _ ) character to be in database name ( if there are more than 1 you should hadle that too )
/*    R e s u l t    (db_suffixes)
source  role_name             db              suffix
------  -------------------  -----------  --------------
Roles   something_user1      something    user1
Roles   something_someuser   something    someuser
Roles   DB_A_user1           DB_A         user1
Dbs     null                 DB_B         null
Dbs     null                 DB_C         null
Dbs     null                 DB_A         null
Roles   DB_B_user3           DB_B         user3             */

... the above resultset should be self joined and the final result is selected using Case expressions...
--        M a i n   S Q L :
--    self joined db_suffixes cte
SELECT Distinct DB_NAME_S as DB_NAME, DB_ROLE_S as DB_ROLE 
FROM   ( Select     d.SOURCE, d.DB, r.ROLE_NAME, r.SUFFIX, 
                    Case When Not EXISTS(Select 1 From databases Where DB_NAME = d.DB) Then Null
                         When d.DB || '_' || r.SUFFIX = r.ROLE_NAME Then d.DB
                         When Coalesce(r.ROLE_NAME, r.SUFFIX) Is Null Then d.DB
                    End as DB_NAME_S, 
                  --
                    Case When Not EXISTS(Select 1 From databases Where DB_NAME = d.DB) Then r.ROLE_NAME
                         When d.DB || '_' || r.SUFFIX = r.ROLE_NAME Then r.ROLE_NAME
                         When Coalesce(r.ROLE_NAME, r.SUFFIX) Is Null Then Null
                    End as DB_ROLE_S
         From       db_suffixes d
         Left Join  db_suffixes r ON(r.SOURCE = 'Roles' And r.DB = d.DB)
       )

/*    R e s u l t :
db_name db_role
------- ------------------------
DB_A    DB_A_user1
DB_B    DB_B_user3
DB_C    null
null    something_someuser
null    something_user1         */

